# FourierTransform a function doesn't give result when variable is 0

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to get a Fourier Transform of a function. However it doesn' work when the variable is 0. I used *Mathematica* 8.0 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 system. The code is as follows:

Defining parameters and constants:

```
Rr = Sqrt[0.999*0.95]; 
λ = 0.561*10^-3; 
f = 100;
W = 0.35;

θ = 1.03*π/180 
t = 2.6*1.47;
Δx[n_] := n 2 t Sin[θ]; 
Δz[n_] := n 2 t Cos[θ];

w = (λ*f)/(π*W);
k = 2 Pi/λ;
b =  k w^2/2;
q = I b;
zr = Pi w^2/λ;
F = 100; 
nbeams = 120;
```

Function definitions:

```
Beam[x_, y_, n_] := Rr^n*Exp[-(((x - Δx[n])^2 + y^2)/ (w^2))]
Field[x_] := Sum[Beam[x, 0, n], {n, 0, nbeams, 1}];
T1[xf_, yf_, n_] := 
  Exp[-I k Δz[n]] Exp[I k Δz[n] (xf^2 + yf^2)/(2 F^2)] 
   FourierTransform[Beam[x, y, n], {x , y}, {-k xf /F, -k yf/ F}]
T2[xf_, yf_] := Sum[T1[xf, yf, n], {n, 0, nbeams}]
```

Getting the results:

```
Table[Abs[T2[xf, 0]]^2, {xf, -1, 1, 0.1}]
```

The results it gives me is :

```
{4.8024*10^-14, 1.15696*10^-12, 2.68091*10^-10, 1.64556*10^-10, 
 2.26218*10^-9, 1.50507*10^-7, 3.7152*10^-8, 1.29164*10^-7, 
 8.43299*10^-6, 8.66378*10^-7, 
 Abs[(-0.000614156 - 0.0000682406 I) + (1. + 0. I) FourierTransform[
     1. E^(-384.158 ((0. + x)^2 + y^2)), {x, y}, {0., 0.}]]^2, 
 5.92387*10^-7, 5.05467*10^-6, 5.03941*10^-7, 3.99645*10^-8, 
 6.8095*10^-9, 1.8926*10^-9, 7.41962*10^-10, 1.10782*10^-8, 
 6.31941*10^-12, 8.40441*10^-14}
```

As you can see, it doesn't compute when x is 0.

However, when I tried the same code with *Mathematica* 10.3 on a Windows 7 machine, it could compute without any problem. Do you have any idea about why it doesn't compute when x is 0?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem your experience stems from trying to calculate the symbolic Fourier transform of `Beam` after numerical values have been substituted for `xf` and `yf`. This fails for $0$, as the variables disappear, and in general may not be accurate.

Instead, pre-calculate the symbolic Fourier transform, then substitute in the numerical values of `xf`, `yf`, and `n`. Here is an example, which uses the rest of your definitions unchanged:

```
ftbeam[xf_, yf_, n_] = FourierTransform[Beam[x, y, n], {x, y}, {-k xf/F, -k yf/F}];

T1[xf_, yf_, n_] := Exp[-I k Δz[n]] Exp[I k Δz[n] (xf^2 + yf^2)/(2 F^2)] ftbeam[xf, yf, n]

Table[Abs[T2[xf, 0]]^2, {xf, -1, 1, 0.1}]

(* Out:
{4.8024*10^-14, 1.15696*10^-12, 2.68091*10^-10, 1.64556*10^-10, 
 2.26218*10^-9, 1.50507*10^-7, 3.7152*10^-8, 1.29164*10^-7, 
 8.43299*10^-6, 8.66378*10^-7, 4.77163*10^-7, 5.92387*10^-7, 
 5.05467*10^-6, 5.03941*10^-7, 3.99645*10^-8, 6.8095*10^-9, 
 1.8926*10^-9, 7.41962*10^-10, 1.10782*10^-8, 6.31941*10^-12, 
 8.40441*10^-14}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you MarcoB. It really solves the problem. I was struggling on this problem for two days.

Comment: @Charlie I'm glad I could help!